# How to send and receive data on the same line in twisted python?

Tags: python, twisted

I am simulating an SFTP server using twisted python.
i want to send the "ftp>" before getting an input from the user on the same line.
i have tried

> basic.LineOnlyReceiver.sendLine(self, msg)

but it gets the input on a different line
how to make it such as in the image?

example of the output I want to simulate
ftp> any command that the user write should be here on the same line
ftp> pwd

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside reply method that we override, use one of them based on the output you want

```
 def reply(self, key):
          
     self.sendLine(msg) # if you want to send data on separate lines
     self.transport.write(b'ftp> ') # if you want to send data without'/n' delimiter
```